# How to find the status of a running process inside docker container in AWS?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have an application (a task) running in containers in AWS. I need to know its current state and also need to make sure it runs without the container exiting and killing it while in progress.
It's a C++ binary.

1. Service - Creating a service will ensure that its fail-safe but how can I read this information from the outside. I could exit the application with a proper exit code but the service will just recreate the task again and again in this manner which is a burden.

Is there a recommended way to communicate from the process within an ECS container to know what it is doing at the moment?

Comment: You you looking for something kind of like what "top" would give you?  Or are you looking for logs?  The word "Status" is a little ambiguous...  Are you just wanting to know if the process is running?

Comment: More like the logs, but like only a subset of the logs. I could get the entire logs and go through that to find out what the process is doing but wondering if there's a better way to deal with this through the dashboards. Something like going to the service -> task -> (see what the process is doing) updating/calling a function/etc.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two ways to view ECS container logs:

1. SSH into your EC2 instance created by ECS, run `docker ps` to find container ids and `docker logs container_id` to see what is going on in the container. (This will not work if you have created your cluster using Fargate as it does not creates EC2 instance, it only creates a network interface)
2. Configure Cloudwatch on AWS to view container activities. To configure logs you have to create a new version of your task defenition > open container > under storage and logging uncheck *auto configure CloudWatch logs* > select log driver as awslogs > tag your group, region and prefix keys. 
   To view your logs, click on the Task tab in your cluster > open your task > expand your container > bottom section shows Log Configuration with a link to your container logs.